# Binding Textbox to Textblock via a Button, using ViewModels

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, binding, uwp

I am trying to understand the basics of MVVM.

Now I have a basic UWP app where I want to input a text in a `TextBox`, then display that text in a `TextBlock`, after I press a `Button`.

How can I do this using MVVM?

**XAML**

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Width="200" Height="40" Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" ></TextBox>
    <Button  Content="Add" Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.Add}" ></Button>
    <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="{Binding OutPut}" ></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

**MainPageViewModel: (C#)**

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string _OutPut;
    public string OutPut
    {
        get
        {
            return _OutPut;
        }
        set
        {
            _OutPut = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(OutPut));
        }
    }

    private string _FirstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return _FirstName;
        }
        set
        {
            _FirstName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FirstName));
        }
    }


    public void Add()
    { 
        OutPut = FirstName;
        // Debug.WriteLine(Output);
    }
}
```

When I press the button, the input text is displayed in the output window, but how can I get it to be displayed in the `Textblock`?

Comment: You need a command like described in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx to call a method in your view model.

Comment: The Button works (kinda). The method is called, but it won't update the Textblock's text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MainPageViewModel` or `ViewModelBase` has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Simply adding the `PropertyChangedEventHandler` is not enough.

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

or

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Without `INotifyPropertyChanged`, your provided code (I added a `StackPanel` around the controls as the Page can only have 1 content element) does not work on my machine, with `INotifyPropertyChanged` added to the code, it works.

---

Bonus: if you want to use `x:Bind` for all your bindings, you'll have to set `Mode=OneWay` on the `TextBlock` binding, as the default for `x:Bind` is `OneTime`.

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Width="200" Height="40" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" ></TextBox>
    <Button  Content="Add" Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.Add}" ></Button>
    <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.OutPut, Mode=OneWay}" ></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Just got a quick question for you. As I'm using the Template 10 Nuget, I extended ViewModelBase in my MainPageViewModel, which extends BindableBase, which again implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Why is it that I need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged again, when it is a subclass of a class that has implemented that interface?

Comment: You're redefining the event handler and thus hiding the one in BindableBase (polymorphism). If you're using Template10, you should just use the [Set method](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/MVVM) in your property setter.